# Paypal Sandbox personal account not debited

Tags: paypal, cakephp-2.0, payment-gateway

I have integrated Paypal API with my CakePHP application.The transaction is successful. 
The merchant's account is credited. But the buyer's account is not debited at all.

Comment: Can you paste the transaction id for the successful payment?

Comment: Well , before I do that I realized something. I have used direct payment api of paypal. So the amount will be debited from the customer's credit card right? and not the paypal balance. Am I right?

Comment: Ok. That is why the paypal balance of the buyer wasn't deducted. Thank you for your help. Appreciate it.